# Just not sure what I'm doing wrong, been at it a while

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to learn how to code, I'm trying to make a basic form to insert into mysql server that i have locally using  xampp, I'm just not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> My Practice Page </title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?
    $first_name = '';
    $last_name ='';
    $city ='';
    ?>

    $db = MYSQLI_CONNECT('localhost','root','','practiceforms');
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (first name, last name, city) VALUES 
        ('$first_name', '$last_name', '$city')";
    mysqli_query($db, $sql);
    mysqli_close($db);
    echo '<p> User added. </p>';

    <form method="post" action="">
    First Name: <input type="text" name="First Name" value="<?php $first_name;?   >" <br>

    Last Name: <input type="text" name="Last Name" value ="<?php $last_name;?>"<br>

    City: <input type ="text" name="city" value=<?php $city; ?>" <br>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">


    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What's happening, and what's different from what you expect to be happening?

Comment: What's your problem? Are there any errors?

Comment: It's been a while for me as well, but I don't think you can put your variables in single quotes, i.e. `'$city'`.  I think they have to be in double quotes `"$city"` or completely unquoted.

Comment: @Jared, they're inside a double quote, so that's okay.

Answer (score 2):

Theres a handful of problems with the code you've posted.

First, not all code is inside the php tags.

```
<?
$first_name = '';
$last_name ='';
$city ='';
?> // THIS LINE SHOULD BE AT THE END OF THIS BLOCK

$db = MYSQLI_CONNECT('localhost','root','','practiceforms');
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (first name, last name, city) VALUES 
    ('$first_name', '$last_name', '$city')";
mysqli_query($db, $sql);
mysqli_close($db);
echo '<p> User added. </p>';

// RIGHT HERE
?>
```

Second, every time you run this page, its going to try and insert things into the database. Wrap the code with

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    // all your code goes inside this
    // so it only fires when a users presses submit
    $first_name = ''; // i think you get the picture...
}
```

Third, you'll want to set your values.

```
$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
```

Notice on that last one. If for whatever reason, the first_name input was not submitted (maybe the input isnt on the page when the form is submitted, for example) then PHP yells at you about `$_POST['first_name']` not being set when you try to use it so you should do this instead.

```
if (isset($_POST['first_name'])) {
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
}
else {
    $first_name = '';
}
```

Comment: `if(!empty( $_POST['first_name'])){ $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; }` ;-)

Comment: i was going easy on him :), but ill add that in.

Comment: I'd upvote, but am out of votes for today. Good answer though.

Comment: Additionally the value settings are missing the php echo (i.e. no value is being set actually) & for the first name input field there is some invalid spacing in the middle of the php end tag....

Comment: `(first name, last name, city)` spaces in column names. So many things wrong with OP's code, it's enough to make anyone's head spin. Those should be wrapped in ticks `\`` or join them with an underscore. Not to mention some serious SQL injection.

Comment: I'll probably just start over and work it one section at a time instead of trying to understand it all at once.

Comment: Thats probably not a terrible idea. If this is the first time you've done this in a while it may take some time. Looks like you've got the basics down pretty good though.